# java.util.Date 's time is 00:00:00 when save to Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, date

I have an class like this:

`class Runner{
Date start;
Date finish;
}`

and a table in oracle to store runners. My problem is when I set the day:

```
start = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()); //I use java.util.Date
```

And when I use Hibernate to save object to DB. The time is always 00:00:00 (the day is correct).
The column is DATE type. I debugged i found that be before save to db. `start` had right value. I have no idea about this.

Can you guy help me, please?

**Update**: I'm using Hibernate.
my hbm file like:

```
<property name="startDate" type="date">
    <column name="START_DATE" length="7" />
</property>
```

The `finish` is the same. In hibernate, when save: I use `session.save(entity)`.

But when I use query to update `finish` like

`String updateQuery = "UPDATE Runner SET finish = ? WHERE id = ?";`
then use setParameter to set `finish` datetime. It's OK.

Comment: "And when I use spring to save object to DB". You have to put this piece of code, problem lies there.

Comment: I think you should parse your date do java.sql.Date before inserting it in the database, or use java.sql.Date instead.

Are you using JPA, Hibernate, or JDBC?

Comment: @edubriguenti that may solve this problem

Comment: You have to use: `start = new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());` and `setTimestamp()` on your `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Date` class in JDBC stores only the date (as in just year and day). If you want to store also the time of the day you should use the `Timestamp` class, and the methods that go with it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Joni **is** right. The ***JDBC*** class `java.sql.Date` only stores the date (the time part is removed - read the Javadocs). Don't confuse `java.sql.Date` with Oracle's `DATE`. Joni's advise to use `java.sql.Timestamp` for Oracle `DATE` columns *is* the correct answer.

Comment: Except that he already uses java.util.Date, and the problem is how it's written to the database.

Comment: @KarlP: `java.util.Date` is **not** `java.sql.Timestamp`! (and `setTimestamp()` only makes sense when using a `java.sql.Timestamp` as you also correctly suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Since Oracles DATE type have a resolution of milliseconds, it's something in your java code that isn't right.

JPA?  Use TemporalType to specify that it should be handled as a timestamp.

JDBC, use setTimestamp. (Perhaps setObject might work.)

Answer (score 0):

Java data class only store the date if you want to store date with time you need to use    java.sql.Timestamp, and in data database field must be datetime datatype.